# Get records Z-Score based on their type

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning

Please consider this records:

```
Id        Type       Price
---------------------------
 1         1          100
 2         2          200
 3         1          150
 4         1          300
 5         2          200
 6         2          400
 7         2          500
```

Based on this Article: [Simple Anomaly Detection Using Plain SQL](https://hakibenita.com/sql-anomaly-detection) I want to calculate Z-Score based on every Type. I mean first I want to partition records based on `Type` column and then in every partition I calculate Z-Score. I wrote this query but I don't know how can I combine this with `Partition` function:

```
WITH series AS (
SELECT Price
FROM MyTable AS n
),
     stats AS (
     SELECT avg(Price) series_avg,
            stddev(Price) as series_stddev
FROM series
),
zscores AS (
              SELECT  Id, Type, Price, (price - series_avg) / series_stddev AS zscore
              FROM  series, stats
           )
SELECT *,case when zscore NOT BETWEEN -1 AND 1 then 'T' else 'F' end AS is_anomaly
FROM zscores;
```

Thanks

Comment: What is a "z-score"? You created the tag, but didn't add any excerpt or wiki information, so you *need* to explain (though I suggest you also add the excerpt and wiki information for your new tag is you want it to remain).

Comment: Where is the `n` coming from in this `(n - series_avg)`?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: You are right. sorry. I corrected it

Comment: @Larnu: How can I add info for z-score? Please guide me

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/155668) the tag your created, @Arian . Though you should, as I asked, also explain in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you calculate the AVG & STDEV simply group by the Type.

Then join the data to the summary on the Type.

> ```
> WITH CTE_DATA AS (
>   SELECT Id, [Type], Price
>   FROM YourTable
> )
> , CTE_STATS AS (
>   SELECT
>     [Type]
>   , AVG(Price) AS series_avg
>   , STDEV(Price) AS series_stddev
>   FROM CTE_DATA
>   GROUP BY [Type]
> )
> , CTE_ZSCORES AS (
>   SELECT d.Id, d.[Type], d.Price
>   , (d.price - st.series_avg) / st.series_stddev AS zscore
>   FROM CTE_DATA d
>   JOIN CTE_STATS st ON d.[Type] = st.[Type]
> )
> SELECT *
> , CASE 
>   WHEN zscore NOT BETWEEN -1 AND 1 
>   THEN 'T' 
>   ELSE 'F' 
>   END AS is_anomaly
> FROM CTE_ZSCORES
> ORDER BY [Type], Id;
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | Type | Price |             zscore | is_anomaly
> -: | ---: | ----: | -----------------: | :---------
>  1 |    1 |   100 | -0.797438205949334 | F         
>  3 |    1 |   150 | -0.317053744534072 | F         
>  4 |    1 |   300 |   1.12409963971171 | T         
>  2 |    2 |   200 | -0.833333333333333 | F         
>  5 |    2 |   200 | -0.833333333333333 | F         
>  6 |    2 |   400 |                0.5 | F         
>  7 |    2 |   500 |   1.16666666666667 | T
> ```

Or use window functions with partitioning.

> ```
> SELECT *
> , CASE 
>   WHEN zscore NOT BETWEEN -1 AND 1 
>   THEN 'T' 
>   ELSE 'F' 
>   END AS is_anomaly
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT Id, [Type], Price
>   , zscore = (Price - AVG(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY [Type])) / STDEV(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY [Type])
>   FROM YourTable
> ) q
> ORDER BY [Type], Id
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | Type | Price |             zscore | is_anomaly
> -: | ---: | ----: | -----------------: | :---------
>  1 |    1 |   100 | -0.797438205949334 | F         
>  3 |    1 |   150 | -0.317053744534072 | F         
>  4 |    1 |   300 |   1.12409963971171 | T         
>  2 |    2 |   200 | -0.833333333333333 | F         
>  5 |    2 |   200 | -0.833333333333333 | F         
>  6 |    2 |   400 |                0.5 | F         
>  7 |    2 |   500 |   1.16666666666667 | T
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=50824bd6803cb4db2bf6dbfc6863ffc9)*

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single scan of the base table and without any joins, using window functions

```sql
SELECT
  t.Id,
  t.Type,
  t.Price,
  (Price - AVG(t.Price) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Type)) /
    STDEV(t.Price) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Type) as zscore
FROM MyTable t
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c1d30b1bc176c8e8615dabcb3919d8ba)